# Connect to Windows Server 2012 Essentials without creating new user login for Windows

Tags: sql-server, windows-8, essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

Is it possible to connect to a Windows Server 2012 Essentials without having to create a new user login for Windows?

I want to just take someones Windows 8 machine and connect it to the server to allow it to access the database without having to have them have to create a new Windows login account to access it.

We have a Windows Server 2012 Essentials domain and a home-grown client/server application that uses SQL Server 2012 as its backend.  That backend requires Windows authentication.  For that reason, I have created both domain and corresponding SQL Server security accounts for a specific set of users.

I'd like these users to be able to authenticate/join the domain for the sole purpose of gaining access to the backend database.  I'd prefer that the other side effects of domain joining, such as a new desktop login, not happen.

Comment: This depends on which SQL database application you're using, and how it's configured. At the very least, you will need to configure a user account in the database for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's nothing in your app preventing this, a user should be able to authenticate to the application using the format `domain-name\username` for the username, e.g. If I had an account on the *example* domain and my username there was *robm* then I would use `example\robm`.

This does not require them to join their PC to the domain, though frankly that is likely to be a better idea in the long run.